# Toggle visibility of a layout on onClick

Tags: java, android, layout

I need to set this layout visible when i click a button, my java is like:

```
Layout propLayout = (Layout) findViewById(R.id.properLayout);

    public void propsBtn(View view) {
propLayout.setVisiblity(View.Visible);
}
```

I know I'm totally wrong with the layout line! I'll be very grateful if someone could show me how to set it right :)

This is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mainBackGround"
tools:context="com.myapplication2.app.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

...contents...

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/properLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="8dp">

...contents...           

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste the xml code of the layout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DerGolem gave the right answer but he then deleted it, so I report it here now:

```
//First we set visibility value of interested layout either to gone, visible or invisible
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then under onCreate write like:

```
//specify the button that has to handle visibility  
ImageButton properties = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.propBtn);

//And the layout we want to change is visibility
final LinearLayout propLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.properLayout);

properties.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (propLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            propLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            propLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The another way of toggle, with less lines, if someone likes

```
// button to click
ImageButton properties = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.propBtn);

// and LinearLayout to toggle
final LinearLayout propLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.properLayout);

properties.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        propLayout.setVisibility((propLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
          ? View.INVISIBLE 
          : View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int counter = 0;
    TextVeiw tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button button = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.but);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    counter++;
    if(counter%2==0){
        tv.setVisibility(View.Visible);//show
    } else {
        tv.setVisibility(View.Gone);//hide
    }
}
});
```

Comment: He wants to toggle the layout's visibility. This will only set it to visible every time the `Button` is clicked.

Comment: Thank for the answer :) however.. I'm trying to set a Layout visibility, not a textview. That's my problem, I don't know how to programm the layout definition line in Java

Comment: just replace your view with the textview any thing that inherits from view is going to be toggled

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set an `OnClickListener()` on the layout you want to toggle. Then inside the listener you check to see if the layout is visible or not. If it is, then you set its visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`. Otherwise, you set it to `View.VISIBLE`.